# I am the iris of the big bang - What am I?

Tags: riddle

I feel I've made this far too easy but it should still be good for a bit of fun.  :)

> I speak out over ocean waves,
>
> I help the seeking find,
>
> So many names that I can have,
>
> George and Jack spring to mind.
>
> Not the iris in your eye,
>
> Droop like the hangman's halter,
>
> Walking me should be easy,
>
> but know me best when you falter.

**What am I?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Flag?

I speak out over ocean waves,

> Flag on a ship
>  **OP:** Yep - specifically I was thinking of the flags used to convey messages but well done :)

I help the seeking find,

> Flag indicating something
>  **OP:** Yep, as in a flagged images on websites etc.

So many names that I can have,

> there are many different flags

George and Jack spring to mind.

> Union Jack  St George's flag
>  **OP:** Well done :)

Not the iris in your eye,

> Not sure about this one
>  **OP:** A 'flag' iris is a type of plant

Droop like the hangman's halter,

> If there is no wind the flag will droop
>  **OP:** To flag can mean to droop or hang loosely

Walking me should be easy,

> You can carry a flag around
>  **OP:** 'Flag Stones' are easy to walk on.

but know me best when you falter.

> *To flag* is a synonym for *to falter*, with a connotation of fading.
>  **OP:** When you've been walking a while you'll begin to flag (get tired)

Comment: Correct. +1  Want me to add my explanations or do you want to try to finish the rest for +10 completely imaginary points?  (Figured George and Jack would give it away)

Comment: @BrentHackers Yes, please, I can't think of the two missing lines. Please edit my answer.

Comment: The last clue: it's a synonym for that. The second-to-last clue: it's another name, you'll know if you check the appropriate Wikipedia pages. I've edited myself, if @BrentHackers will take some time.

Comment: @RadoslavHristov  Added a few explanations.

Comment: I had a feeling it would be this, especially after the Jack/George clue, but didn't get around to checking the rest before you answered.

Comment: What is the "iris of the big bang" part about?

Comment: @DasBeasto THAT is now sort of a very vague pop culture tv reference to the answer.  It was going to form part of the puzzle but got dropped but I then neglected to update the title...